# How to set Custom Id to my document in document library?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, jquery

When user upload the document I want to set the value to my custom column like Id
.Suppose user add new document I want to set column value how can I do this?

Comment: What type of value you want to store in your column? Is it an iterating calculated value? OR would you like the user to specify that value?

Comment: User specify value

Comment: what is your issue here, once you have add a new column in your library and try to upload the document it should ask you to add the metadata columns for this document so the user can specify it ? so till now i don;t what's the issue ? :)